# Illustrator CS6 document setup background color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, background, document-setup

I have a problem with background color in Illustrator CS6. So i set up a desired color for background in document setup, but then i can`t see any white color within my document (i assume that white is transaprent). Any advice how can i fix this?

Comment: Is this for print or web work? If for print, are you going to print on a colored stock?

Comment: Hi there, it is for web work (logo).

Comment: For web design, I'd simply use @Oscarpas solution and draw a rectangle and lock it. The document set up trick is really best for print work.

Comment: To see things easier, I'll usually work with another color other than white and then recolor those pieces to white, when I'm finished.  The rectangle trick is the best route, if you have a complicated design though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no fix for this as far as I know. Illustrator doesn't treat white as a color, but as a lack of color. So changing the documents background color changes how white, or rather the absence of color, is displayed. The background color will also alter any colors you place on it.

This makes sense if you imagine how things print in the real world – you don't usually print white and the paper you choose will affect how colors are printed.

To deal with backgrounds I usually create a bottom layer, drag out a rectangle that fits my Artboard, add my desired color and lock the layer.